# Can one increase the hard limit for a ulimit parameter in Mac OS 10.7 (OS X Lion)?

Tags: c, macos, coredump, ulimit

Unfortunately, while trying to delete previous core dumps, I set my core file size hard limit to 0. Is there a way to change the hard limit of a ulimit parameter?

```
host-101-178:Labs evan$ ulimit -c 0
host-101-178:Labs evan$ ulimit -c 1000000
-bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
host-101-178:Labs evan$ ulimit -c unlimited
-bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
host-101-178:Labs evan$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 2560
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
host-101-178:Labs evan$ ulimit -c unlimited
-bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What does the output of **sysctl -a | grep core** say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log out and log back in and the hard coredumpsize limit will be back to the default.  Use

```
ulimit -S -c
```

to change the soft limit.